# Pending incoming BTC to Coinbase

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, coinbase.com

I sent BTC from lending platform to Coinbase on Jan 2nd.  Still shows pending.

Can anyone provide any info and assistance in getting this transaction completed?

f69f851197a7b9bd8cf3e85a2436ed51e1049fa4b277273e074708de34540288

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/f69f851197a7b9bd8cf3e85a2436ed51e1049fa4b277273e074708de34540288/

Answer (score 0):

You can download Electrum and create new transaction from output with higher fee, it's called "Child pay for parent"

You hsould have access to oone of output addresses.

Comment: Thank you.  How do i find one of the output addresses?

Comment: It's seems being confirmed, thakfully.  Electrum allows child pay for parent by simply two clicks of mouse, otherwose, there are complicated tutorials, google "btc child pay for parent"